# Drupal 8 views contextual filter using product type and a taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-commerce

I'm having troubles getting the contextual filter to work on a view.

I want `products/type/kind` to show only the products which have a Product Type of `type` and have `kind` as a term in a particular vocabulary.

`type` and `kind` contain values which include spaces. I think at least part of my problem is converting spaces in `type` to a dashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it working. Set the contextual filter for when a filter value is not available to 'provide a default value', type of 'Raw Value from URL'.

Set the 'When the filter value is available or a default is provided' to validate the type you want. For the term, I /think/ you need taxonomy term name (possibly taxonomy term name as term id).

Be careful to use machine names for product type (ie spaces in machine names are _'s) and to replace spaces with -'s in taxonomony terms. This is where I was getting caught.